# Problem solving involving profit and loss

Tags: arithmetic

A fruit seller buys a large quantity of apples for $\$150$. $200$ of the apples are rotten and he sells each of the remaining apples at $10$ cents more than what he paid and makes a profit of $\$50$. Find the number of apples that he brought originally.

Attempt:

Let $x$ be  number of apples brought

Remaining apples = $x-200$

Selling price of $(x-200)$ apples = $ 150 + 50 = 200 $

After here I'm confused and not sure what to do next. Can I get a hint

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You have made the correct observations. The vendor bought the original $x$ apples for $\$150$ so that she/he sells the $x-200$ 'good' apples for $\$200$ - hence the $\$50$ profit. But you have not used the price. Let $p$ be the original price of the apples. Can you write two equations using the number of apples and the price of them using your knowledge of the original purchase and the amount the vendor makes selling them? This should give you everything you need to know.

Comment: Oh yes , I got what u mean . But I only can find out 1 equation which is $ X - 200 = p + 0.10 $